# Drag & drop list view item on a Datagrid header in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid, drag-and-drop

Trivial, but I got really stuck on it... How on Earth can I find out which DataGrid column (or header) the item was dropped on?? I can see no retrievable info on that within the `DataGrid.Drop` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just programming some dataGrid D&D at the moment, and the only way I've found to do what you ask is to put the Drop listener on each dataGridColumnHeader and on each DataGridCell.

as I write, I've got Drop listeners on my cells, dataGridColumnHeaders and datagrids (for the drop in the background of the datagrid, in case you haven't got enough rows/columns to fill the DG).

those listeners get the cell's Row/col index where it applies using something like `myDataGrid.Columns.IndexOf(((DataGridCell)sender).Column)` in the cell's drop listener and then call a common method in my DG's class.

it's actually not as messy as you'd think.

**edit:** regarding your comment: "But how do you attach an event handler to DataGrid header?"

in your MyDataGrid.xaml for instance:

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <EventSetter Event="DropEvent" Handler="ColumnHeaderDropHandler" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

and of course, you need to implement ColumnHeaderDropHandler in your code behind.

Comment: But how do you attach an event handler to `DataGrid` header?

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting an error: `Error 1 The type reference cannot find a public type named 'DataGridColumnHeader'.`

Comment: Nevermind; I got it to work. Namespace references in XAML are not very intuitive, and I'm not too good at WPF. Your solution works all right - thanks for help.